# my PHP not return JSON

Tags: php, json

I try to learn basic PHP to connect between my server and android
but I have a problem with my basic PHP it return html instead JSON.

this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("sql100.0fees.us","*********","*******");
mysql_select_db("db shlomi");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from pru");
$output=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
   $output[]= array(
       'name' => $row['name'],
     'quantity' => $row['quantity']);
}
echo(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

when I run this in my browser I receive
[{"name":"10","quantity":"50"},{"name":"10","quantity":"50"}]

but in my app or in jsonlint.com
I receive error like html

```
<html><body><scripttype="text/javascript"src="/aes.js"></script><script>functiontoNumbers(d){
    vare=[

    ];d.replace(/(..)/g,
    function(d){
        e.push(parseInt(d,
        16))
    });returne
}functiontoHex(){
    for(vard=[

    ],
    d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[
        0
    ].constructor==Array?arguments[
        0
    ]: arguments,
    e="",
    f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[
        f
    ]?"0": "")+d[
        f
    ].toString(16);returne.toLowerCase()
}vara=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
c=toNumbers("68c0fc9ff46cfabf092145e84011ee13");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,
2,
a,
b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="http://ranva.0fees.us/query.php?ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>ThissiterequiresJavascripttowork,
pleaseenableJavascriptinyourbrowseroruseabrowserwithJavascriptsupport</noscript></body></html>
```

so I understand that my problem is in the PHP because it didn't return JSON.

Comment: Wut? What exactly do you receive "in jsonlint or my app"?!

Comment: its not with php it seems , cos u r getting it in json output in browser ..  Be clear !

Comment: hi, i believe you did return json. json_encode is the right function to use. The issues is with something else other than in php.

Comment: php is obviously creating json.. what's your problem exactly?

Comment: Your application is returning valid json.

Comment: in my app and in jsonlint when i enter my url.php i receive answer like html so i cannot parser this to json,

Comment: this is my eror from jsonhint
Parse error on line 1:
<html><body><scriptt
^
Expecting '{', '['

Answer (score 0):

The response generated by your script is JSON but it is advertised as HTML in the header of the response because the default `Content-Type` returned by PHP scripts is `text/html`.

If your script generates anything else than HTML it has to mention this in the response by sending the correct `Content-Type` using the PHP function [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

The correct content type for JSON content is `application/json`. Use the function `header()` to set the correct content type before sending any content to the browser.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo(json_encode($output));
```

#### Very important!

The [`mysql` PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and it was removed from PHP 7.
Forget it!

Learn and use either [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is serving the HTML page to block "strange access" to your server.
I read something about it in the following post:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/it-looks-like-this-is-a-web-page-not-a-feed-i-looked-for-a-feed-associated

Maybe accessing from your app will be classified as "strange access".

Please contact your provider and ask them, if there is any protection guard (e.g. the "Spam shield function") enabled.